# Keep singleton instance of java application

Tags: java, swing, jframe, single-instance

I have a jar file that displays a `JFrame` when it is executed.
I don't want to allow duplicate execution of my Jar file.
Every time before creating the frame, using Java I want check whether the Jar is already executing. If my app. already has an instance on-screen, I want to bring it to front.

How can I do that?
Please suggest me a way.

Comment: You have only 2 ways to make it happen: Either a file listener or create a bean with a boolean flag set.

Comment: The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). It includes many handy API's including the [`SingleInstanceService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html) which *"..allow applications launched under Java Web Start to register themselves as singletons, and to be passed in new parameter sets when user attempts to launch new instances of them."*

Comment: *"You have only 2 ways to make it happen:"*  Famous last words.  See my comment.  It might use either of those ways, or something else entirely (such as securing a `ServerSocket`), but as long as it works reliably x-platform, why worry about the implementation details?

Answer (score 8):

**There is no regular method in java for single instance of an application.**
However you can use `Socket` programming technique to achieve your goal.

When the instance is creating it attempts to listen a `ServerSocket`. If it could open the `ServerSocket` it means there are no another instance of the application. So, it keeps the `ServerSocket` live until the program is shutdown. If it could not open the ServerSocket, it means the application already have another instance. So you can exit application silently. **Additionally you don't need to reset your settings when shutdown the application.**

**Try following example**

```
public class SingletonApplication extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    //count of tried instances
    private int triedInstances = 0;
    //the port number using
    private static final int PORT = 5555;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingletonApplication application = new SingletonApplication();
        application.setTitle("My Singleton Application");
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(500, 500);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SingletonApplication() {
        super();

        //run socket listening inside a thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //create server socket
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

            //listing the socket to check new instances
            while (true) {
                try {
                    //another instance accessed the socket
                    serverSocket.accept();
                    //bring this to front
                    toFront();

                    //change the title (addtional);
                    triedInstances++;
                    setTitle("Tried another instances : " + triedInstances);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //cannot accept socket
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //fail if there is an instance already exists
            try {
                //connect to the main instance server socket
                new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), PORT);
            } catch (IOException ex1) {
                //do nothing
            } finally {
                //exit the system leavng the first instance
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Additionally: **It can pass your runtime arguments into the main instance of the application via the client `Socket`.** So, it's possible to make the main instance to perform required task such opening file or playing music by adding some additional code to read the `InputStream` of accepted `Socket` when calling **`accept()`** method.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same situation.

What I did is I used to open a `file` in `write` mode and `delete` the `file` when I close the application.

By doing this I have a known proof that my program is running.

Each time I open the application I check for the existence of that file and if I find my file, it is running then I used to alert him

**"An instance is already running".**

Even if one tries to delete that file it says that it is open in another application.

Comment: if your application unexpectedly closed, then you will not be able to run the application permanently. and you cannot bring the application to the front.

Comment: you're right.... that's a valid reason we shall not use File approach rather than socket.

Answer (score 3):

I used a socket too, via RMI.

The application is an RMI host/server, accepts a Remote Method Invokation on a port.

In the main, at startup on tries as RMI client to get an RMI server on that port.
Is it there one does a remote call passing the command line args (to open another document for instance). And then quits.

As a server on being called that remote method one brings the application to front using `toFront()` of the window.

Answer (score 2):

[JUnique](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/) accomplishes the first part--blocking multiple instances of the same program.  Getting the existing instance to come to the front is another task that I'm not sure how to approach.